# How do you format percentages when outputting a df from python to excel?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have code I have wrote that correctly outputs numbers formatted as percentages to excel, however, it appears that I run into an error when trying to convert negative values to percentages.

Below is the current code format I am using

```py
percentValues = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})
```

The following is the the error I am getting:

```py
UserWarning: Col number -1 must be >= 0
  warn("Col number %d must be >= 0" % col)
```

Hopefully there is a format that can also convert negative values to percents.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code that is raising that error? The error reads like it has nothing to do with negative numbers, rather you're using an invalid column index.

Comment: if you're certain the problem involves negative numbers, then maybe try defining your format: `{'num_format': '0.00%;-0.00%'}`